# Parse Date from MongoDB with Gson

Tags: java, mongodb, date, gson

In my MongoDB a document looks like this:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5613700bc00eac21886b6a51"), 
"firstname" : "Marc", 
"lastname" : "Anonymous", 
"email" : "marc.XXXXXX@hotmail.com", 
"phone" : "+41/12/345678", 
"timestamp" : ISODate("2015-10-06T06:54:03.905+0000"), 
"state" : "waiting"
}
```

I am using gson to parse the json into my Java class User which has a variable timestamp and is a Date but I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 179 path $.timestamp`

I insert the timestamp into MongoDb via Date too. I don't know how to handle this. Should I just use a String and convert it every time I need in in Date form?

```
public class User {

public String firstname;
public String lastname;
public String email;
public String phone;
public Date timestamp;
public String state;

public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
} 
//...
```

### Edit

I get the json via the MongoDb Java driver. The error occurs when I want to deserialize the String with gson

```
public ArrayList<User> findUserByEmail(String email) {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    ArrayList<User> l = new ArrayList<>();
    MongoDatabase db = con.getDatabase("waitinglist");
    MongoCollection col = db.getCollection("users");

    MongoCursor<Document> f = col.find(eq("email", email)).iterator();
    while (f.hasNext()) {
        Document d = f.next();
        System.out.println(d.toJson());
        l.add(g.fromJson(d.toJson(), User.class));
    }
    return l;
}
```

d.toJson() returns

```
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "5613700bc00eac21886b6a51"
},
"firstname": "Marc",
"lastname": "xxxx",
"email": "marc.xxxxxx@hotmail.com",
"phone": "+41/12/345678",
"timestamp": {
   "$date": 1444114443905
 },
"state": "waiting"
}
```

The error is being thrown because the Date gets convertetd into an own document and when I want to deseriazable it with Gson the Json does not fit with my class.

Comment: Marc, I anonymized the sample data you have given. Maybe it was already the case, but I couldn't really tell and just wanted to make sure that you don't get spammed all over.

Comment: Please show us the code of your DAO.

Comment: As requested by @MarkusWMahlberg, your definition is important here. The driver layer itself should just return `java.util.Date` classed objects, but it is all about what annotations or configuration you are using with Gson. Presumably you are expecting a "string" when you should not.

Comment: I added my class @BlakesSeven. I never had to use any annotations for gson. Can you help me here?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thank you for anonymizing my data. I will consider it next time :)

Comment: Perhaps the reverse case is true here. Have not used Gson for a while, but my memory recalls it needs to know a registered serializer to convert to JSON. How are you in fact reading the data from MongoDB? Are you sure that is where the error occurs? Or is the error occuring when you ask to serialize to JSON instead?

Comment: @BlakesSeven I am reading the data with the java mongo driver. I get a Document an pass it to gson with `doc.toJson()`. I just saw that this returns the Json like: `.. "timestamp" : { "$date" : 1444114443905 }, ..`

Comment: @marcmaann Probably a lot better again to show exactly what you are doing and where in fact the error you report is occuring within the context of your question rather than posting in commnents. You have already edited the question before so you know where the link is. Please keep your additional information in the question and just use comments to notify those who asked about the changes instead.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I think you are right, GSON got to be registered. But I am no too convinced wether doing all the stuff "by hand" is a proper solution here. From my feeling, morphia would be a good start (and proper for most cases, too), wouldn't it? There has to be a very good reason to deal with the pain-in-the-neck(-ish) intricacies and subtleties of JSON (de-)serialization. What do you think?

Comment: @BlakesSeven added my code

Comment: @marcmaann So where is the eror being thrown? Seems to be doing the job as far as I can see.

Comment: @BlakesSeven when I want to deserialize the json with gson. edited it.

Comment: And eventually we get to that your question is the complete opposite of what you asked. Where in fact your intention is to covert a "JSON String" or in fact "object with a string value" into your Java object. Which would have been a much clearer question to directly ask.

Comment: I didn't know that the Json string would look like that, I just found out myself..

Comment: The problem is your JSON has a field "timestamp" that is an embedded object but your class definition (`Date timestamp`) is telling GSON to convert this to a Date object type. Your JSON just doesn't match your POJO.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by using [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) and changing your code to the following:

```
public ArrayList<User> findUserByEmail(String email) {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    ArrayList<User> l = new ArrayList<>();
    Jongo jongo = con.getDB("waitinglist");

    Iterator<User> users = jongo.getCollection("users").find("{email: #}", email).as(User.class).iterator();
    while(users.hasNext()){
        l.add(users.next());
    }
    return l;
}
```

Otherwise you're going to have to do something like the following...

Make a wrapper class like this

```
public static class GsonCompatibleDate {
    @SerializedName("$date")
    public Long date;

    public GsonCompatibleDate(Long date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return new Date(date);
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date.getTime();
    }
}
```

- Note the annotation `@SerializedName("$date")`. This just lets you use a nicer Java-style name for your variable;

Update your POJO to this or something similar:

```
public class User {

    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String email;
    public String phone;
    public GsonCompatibleDate timestamp;
    public String state;

    public Date getTimestamp() {
          return timestamp.getDate();
    }
}
```

Your de-serialization code would stay exactly as it was before. The updated POJO now matches your Mongo JSON output.

I tested both methods and they work for me. I also highly recommend using a library like Jongo, Morphia, etc... instead of using the Mongo driver itself, unless absolutely necessary.